# Is there any way to get a pointer to an "in" parameter of generic type?

Tags: c#

I have a bit of performance-critical hardware interop code that, for optimization reasons (yes, I profiled) takes a generic struct parameter as a `ref` (even though it doesn't actually modify the parameter) and then uses the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) class to convert that to a pointer that can be passed to the hardware driver. Here's an example:

```
unsafe void DoPerformanceCriticalThing<T>(ref T myThing)
    where T : struct
{
    void* ptr = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref myThing);
    // Give ptr to low-level hardware driver.
}
```

Because this code (including the hardware driver to which `ptr` is passed) never actually modifies `myThing`, the presence of `ref` is misleading and I'd like to change it to an `in` parameter (a feature added in C# 7.2). However, an `in` parameter can't be passed forward as a `ref` argument, and the `Unsafe` class doesn't (yet?) support `in` parameters.

So my question is, is there any way to change `ref T myThing` to `in T myThing` and still be able to get a pointer to it?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that `DoPerformanceCriticalThing<T>(in T myThing) ... Unsafe.AsPointer(ref myThing)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Rhumborl Correct: `in T myThing` doesn't work because an `in` can't be converted to a `ref` and the `Unsafe` class doesn't have any `in` overloads for any of its methods.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I finally figured out how to do this with the new ['unmanaged' generic constraint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/06/12/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/) in C# 7.3. With this new constraint applied to the generic type, it then becomes possible to declare a pointer of that generic type and get the address of the parameter using the `fixed` statement:

```
unsafe void DoPerformanceCriticalThing<T>(in T myThing)
    where T : unmanaged
{
    fixed(T* ptr = &primitive)
    {
        // Give ptr to low-level hardware driver.
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `unmanaged` constraint is more restrictive than the `struct` constraint because it prevents the type from containing any references to managed objects, but I suspect that in most cases (including all of my own cases) this won't be a problem in practice.